# ajax result div refresh in struts2

Tags: ajax, jquery, struts2

i Have an use  case

```
<html>
<head>
    <s:head />
    <sj:head jqueryui="true" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
              $.subscribe('hideTarget', function(event, data) {
                $('#'+event.originalEvent.targets).hide("blind");
                });
     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="left" >
        <div class="demo" align="center"><a href="#" id="button">Run Effect</a></div>
        <div id="effect" style="display:none;">
            Upload Photos Here
            <s:form action="AjaxTest" method="post" theme="xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <s:file name="userImage" label="User Image" />
                <sj:submit targets="result" effect="blind" effectMode="show" onEffectCompleteTopics="hideTarget" value="Upload" button="true" />
            </s:form>
            <br/>
            <img id="indicator" src="progressbar.gif" style="display:none" alt="loading"/> 
        </div>
        <sj:div  effect="pulsate" effectDuration="1500" onEffectCompleteTopics="hideTarget" cssClass="welcome" id="result"></sj:div>
    </div>
    <!-- End demo -->
</body>
```

as u can see i am uploading an single file using ajax call. when u click Run Effect link a div will toggle down in that file tag willbe their, select the file, upload it and it will display successfully uploaded message with effect and after it hide that success message.
**up to that it work fine but my problem is when u want to upload another file it will display file tag u can select also but when u submit the form it is not displaying an  successful message but file is uploaded in server and also in file tag previous uploaded file name is their**

**NOTE: my requirement is it should show successfully uploaded message for each and every time user submits form using ajax call**

my success.jsp is

```
<body>
   <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
       <s:actionmessage/>
    </s:if>
    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
            <s:actionerror/>
    </s:if>
</body>
```

Struts.xml

```
 <action name="AjaxTest" class="AjaxCallAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

just like the link below this
http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

Comment: If you are familiar with jQuery get rid of those sj tags and use jquery directly... then you can do what ever you want (you you can then ask questions which are ONLY tagged with jquery and get snappy answers). The problem is ajax tags are awkward.  Most veteran struts2 users know a JS framework(s) of choice so few here can help (why use a clumsy tag library when there is a much better way), jQuery users can't help because the details are hidden behind a tag library.

Comment: thanks than any suggestion how to over come that in jquery

Comment: Sorry it will be be a while before I can respond... but I use the struts2-json-plugin on the actions I want to use ajax on. Rework the question to hide as much details as possible about the server when asking client side questions.  Simply state: Here is what I want, here is what I've tried the JS/HTML(maybe css) I have so far, and this is what the server sends back when I use this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use id="result" in , use name="result" and use formIds in